# Remove values from Ruby map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dictionary

I have an object that looks like this in Rails console:

```
  pry(#<User>)> favorite_foods
  => [#<FavoriteFood id: 3, food_id: 1, user_id: 1, removed: false, created_at: "2015-09-06 00:49:35", updated_at: "2015-09-06 00:49:35">,
  #<FavoriteFood id: 4, food_id: 2, user_id: 1, removed: true, created_at: "2015-09-06 12:16:56", updated_at: "2015-09-06 12:17:36">]
```

favorite_foods is in a polymorphic relationship with foods.

```
has_many :favorite_foods
has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_foods, source: :food
has_many :foods, through: :favorite_foods
```

In the favorite_food.rb model, I'm setting favorite foods by using this method:

```
 def favorited_foods
   favorite_foods.map(&:food_id).to_set
 end
```

I need to be able to remove all instances of favorite_foods where the field "removed" equals true.

For example: from the console session above, I want favorite_foods to include food_id 3, not food_id 4.

What is a clean way to do this in the favorited_foods method? I tried incorporating .reject and it ignored it.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just simply do:

```
FavoriteFood.where(removed: true).delete_all
```

which will delete all the `FavoriteFood` records where `removed is true`.

If you want to do it using `map`, then you can do:

```
favorited_foods.select { |f| f.removed == true }.map { |f| f.delete }
```

but this is not recommended as it will call `delete` method once for each record. The better way is deleting them all using [delete_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/delete_all/class) as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something like:

```
def remove_favorited_foods
  favorite_foods.each {|food| Food.destroy(food) if food.removed?}
end
```

You should also add `has_many :foods, dependent: :destroy, through: :favorite_foods` to your model to ensure that the favorite foods are destroyed accordingly. See [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).